# Device Tree Configuration for PTN5110 with an iMX6UL and Kernel 5.15

Tags: linux, yocto, device-tree, imx6

Same Hardware, new Kernel

We are trying to update to the new Kernel 5.15.32 (old Kernel 4.19.72) but the USB-PD Chip (PTN5110) just does not work:

When we start the module tcpci with our Device Tree (see below) we get the following messages:

```
devel@europa:/usr/lib/modules/5.15.32+g4122737b2fca$ sudo modprobe tcpci
[  139.282440] OF: graph: no port node found in /soc/bus@2100000/i2c@21f8000/ptn5110@50
[  139.332044] OF: graph: no port node found in /soc/bus@2100000/i2c@21f8000/ptn5110@50/connector
[  139.341524] OF: graph: no port node found in /soc/bus@2100000/i2c@21f8000/ptn5110@50/connector
```

We did try to specify the port but were unlucky so far (nothing seams to work and we are trying for a few weeks now). The DT below worked wonderful in the old kernel but not the new one.
After loading the module we see some communication over the I2C port and everything seams to work fine. As soon as we plug in a USB connection the Kernel gets flooded with IRQ requests (or so it seams). The I2C bus is filled with data exchange and none of the consoles are reacting to any keystroke. After unplugging the USB connection the system reacts normal again. (the system seams to be blocked completely)

Our device tree:

```
/ {
    regulators {
        compatible = "simple-bus";
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;

        reg_usb_otg1_vbus: regulator@2 {
            compatible = "regulator-fixed";
            reg = <2>;
            regulator-name = "usb_otg1_vbus";
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_usb_otg1_vbus>;
            regulator-min-microvolt = <5000000>;
            regulator-max-microvolt = <5000000>;
            gpio = <&gpio2 8 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
            enable-active-high;
            status = "okay";
        };
    };
};

&usbotg1 {
    /*pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_usbotg1>;*/
    dr_mode = "otg";
    status = "okay";
    disable-over-current;
    vbus-supply = <&reg_usb_otg1_vbus>;
};

&i2c4 {
    clock-frequency = <100000>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_i2c4>;
    status = "okay";

    usb_pd: ptn5110@50 {
        compatible = "nxp,ptn5110";
        reg = <0x50>;
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_usb_pd>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gpio2>;
        interrupts = <11 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_LOW>;
        wakeup-source;

        usb_con: connector {
            compatible = "usb-c-connector";
            label = "USB-C";
            data-role = "dual";
            power-role = "dual";
            try-power-role = "sink";
            source-pdos = <PDO_FIXED(VSAFE5V, 2000, PDO_FIXED_USB_COMM | PDO_FIXED_DUAL_ROLE)>;
            sink-pdos = <PDO_FIXED(VSAFE5V, 2000, PDO_FIXED_USB_COMM | PDO_FIXED_DUAL_ROLE)
                                     //PDO_FIXED(VSAFE5V, 3000, 0)
                                     //PDO_FIXED(9000, 3000, 0)
                                     PDO_FIXED(12000, 3000, 0)
                                     PDO_FIXED(20000, 3000, 0)>;
                                     //PDO_FIXED(20000, 5000, 0)>;
            op-sink-microwatt = <10000000>;

        };
    };
};

&iomuxc {
    pinctrl_i2c4: i2c4grp {
        fsl,pins = <
            MX6UL_PAD_UART2_TX_DATA__I2C4_SCL   0x4001b8b0
            MX6UL_PAD_UART2_RX_DATA__I2C4_SDA   0x4001b8b0
        >;
    };

    pinctrl_usb_pd: usbpdgrp {
        fsl,pins = <
            MX6UL_PAD_ENET2_TX_DATA0__GPIO2_IO11    0x0001b020 /* Alert Interrupt */
            MX6UL_PAD_ENET2_TX_CLK__GPIO2_IO14      0x0001b020 /* Fault Interrupt */
        >;
    };

    pinctrl_usb_otg1_vbus: usbotg1 {
        fsl,pins = <
            MX6UL_PAD_ENET2_RX_DATA0__GPIO2_IO08    0x000000b9
            MX6UL_PAD_ENET2_RX_DATA1__USB_OTG1_OC   0x000010b0
        >;
    };
};
```

Comment: Are you reusing an old DT with a newer kernel version? That could be an issue. For instance Microchip explicitly warns its users to "*use a Device Tree Binary and a Kernel Image generated from the same source tree.*" What non-customized **.dtsi** files are you using? Compare the different versions for changes.

Comment: No, we are not using the old .dtb with the new kernel. While building the new Kernel we also build a new .dtb and use this new .dtb. But we are using the old .dts files as a starting point for the new kernel.
The only non-customized .dtsi we are using is the imx6ul-europa.dtsi, everything else we did our self.

Comment: I did search the Internet (and in the Kernel sources) for an example how to use the PTN5110 correctly several times already but could not find anything anywhere. We are trying it since a few weeks now...

Comment: When I do "grep -r -i ptn5110" in the current mainline source tree I get several devicetrees using this that could be used as an example and also a binding documentation in Documentation/devicetree/bindings/usb/typec-tcpci.txt.

Comment: I did try all the examples I could find in the mainline source tree and take a good look at the Documentation but was unable to find a solution that worked.

Comment: So I did find out that the Chip goes into Fault every time I plug in a USB Connection. (It comes out of the Fault as soon as I unplug the USB)

On the I2C Bus I see that the Kernel Module keeps trying to reset the Fault flag without success.

I see a repeating pattern of:

    0x50 Write 0x10
    0x50 Read 0x00 0x02
    0x50 Write 0x10 0x00 0x02

As I wrote, the chip was working fine with the old Kernel 4.19.72 but not with the new Kernel 5.15.68.

If someone could tell me what is going wrong I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out there is a bug in the Kernel Module tcpci that has this effect on the PTN5110 Chip. NXP already has a patch for their Kernel but it was not ported to the Mainline Kernel. I implemented the same patch for the Kernel 5.15.91 and the chip is working flawlessly now. For anyone with the same problem, here my patch:

```
diff --git a/drivers/usb/typec/tcpm/tcpci.c b/drivers/usb/typec/tcpm/tcpci.c
index 5340a3a3a81b..0d715e091b78 100644
--- a/drivers/usb/typec/tcpm/tcpci.c
+++ b/drivers/usb/typec/tcpm/tcpci.c
@@ -628,6 +628,9 @@ static int tcpci_init(struct tcpc_dev *tcpc)
        if (ret < 0)
                return ret;

+       /* Clear fault condition */
+       regmap_write(tcpci->regmap, TCPC_FAULT_STATUS, 0x80);
+
        if (tcpci->controls_vbus)
                reg = TCPC_POWER_STATUS_VBUS_PRES;
        else
@@ -644,7 +647,8 @@ static int tcpci_init(struct tcpc_dev *tcpc)

        reg = TCPC_ALERT_TX_SUCCESS | TCPC_ALERT_TX_FAILED |
                TCPC_ALERT_TX_DISCARDED | TCPC_ALERT_RX_STATUS |
-               TCPC_ALERT_RX_HARD_RST | TCPC_ALERT_CC_STATUS;
+               TCPC_ALERT_RX_HARD_RST | TCPC_ALERT_CC_STATUS |
+               TCPC_ALERT_V_ALARM_LO | TCPC_ALERT_FAULT;
        if (tcpci->controls_vbus)
                reg |= TCPC_ALERT_POWER_STATUS;
        /* Enable VSAFE0V status interrupt when detecting VSAFE0V is supported */
@@ -728,6 +732,13 @@ irqreturn_t tcpci_irq(struct tcpci *tcpci)
                        tcpm_vbus_change(tcpci->port);
        }

+       /* Clear the fault status anyway */
+       if (status & TCPC_ALERT_FAULT) {
+               regmap_read(tcpci->regmap, TCPC_FAULT_STATUS, &raw);
+               regmap_write(tcpci->regmap, TCPC_FAULT_STATUS,
+                               raw | TCPC_FAULT_STATUS_MASK);
+       }
+
        if (status & TCPC_ALERT_RX_HARD_RST)
                tcpm_pd_hard_reset(tcpci->port);
```

I found this solution here: https://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/linux-imx/commit/drivers/usb/typec/tcpm/tcpci.c?h=lf-5.15.y&id=2a263f918b25725e0434afa9ff3b83b1bc18ef74

Answer (score 0):

So I did find out that the Chip goes into Fault every time I plug in a USB Connection. (It comes out of the Fault as soon as I unplug the USB)

On the I2C Bus I see that the Kernel Module keeps trying to reset the Fault flag without success.

I see a repeating pattern of:

- 0x50 Write 0x10
- 0x50 Read 0x00 0x02
- 0x50 Write 0x10 0x00 0x02

As I wrote, the chip was working fine with the old Kernel 4.19.72 but not with the new Kernel 5.15.68.

If someone could tell me what is going wrong I would be very thankful.